# How to save captured region as an image to a disk file?

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

I would like to be able to save a captured region to a png file on disk

The section of the code I have is:

```
r = Region(150,350,1700,630)
r.highlight(15)
screen = Screen()
image = screen.capture(r)
```

How to save now?

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screen.html#capturing), tried to add a path and a name:

```
image = screen.capture(r, "/tmp", "aaa.png")
```

But returns an error:

```
[error] script [ finviz ] stopped with error in line 17
[error] TypeError ( capture(): expected 0-1 or 4 args; got 3 )
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first
line: module ( function ) statement 
17: main (  <module> )     image = screen.capture(r, "/tmp", "aaa.png")
[error] --- Traceback --- end --------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this obscure statement in the documentation:

> (MUST be used as such undotted)

which, when applied blindly...

```
r = Region(150,350,1700,630)
filename = capture(r, "/tmp", "aaa.png")
```

...makes it work !

Comment: I lost a couple of hours trying to make it work.  Thank you so much, all the best to you.